# What exactly does it mean when Chrome reports 'invalid certificate transparency information was supplied by the server?'

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

i have recentrly installed ssl certificate
i have bought it on http://ssls.com/ RapidSSL

but when i am clicking green https:// on url tab into chrome (when i am on ma website)
Chrome reports 'invalid certificate transparency information was supplied by the server?'

whats wrong?
what can i do to fix it?

http://prntscr.com/bqxp7m

i am using cpanel 
also when i am on another page such site.com/blog there isnot any green https tab up there

Comment: And what does it say when you click on the Details link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your SSL provider and ask them to submit your certificate to the certificate transparency program: https://www.certificate-transparency.org/

or buy a certificate from a provider that autmatically do it for you such as https://www.ssltrust.com.au

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was, Avast replace my Intermediate certificate by own, disable Avast, restart browser, its ok now.